# SQL problem with wildcards, strange behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I have got this query:

```html
SELECT Sites.Master_ID AS Master_ID, Scopes.Name AS Scope, Brands.Extension AS [Brand], Sites.ID AS [Site ID], Sites.Name AS [Site Name], Sites.Address, Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name AS Country
From Sites
INNER Join Scopes ON Sites.scope_ID = Scopes.ID
INNER JOIN Brands ON Sites.brand_ID = Brands.ID
INNER Join Countries ON Sites.country_ID = Countries.ID
WHERE CONCAT (Scopes.Name, Brands.Extension, Sites.ID, Sites.Name, CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),Sites.Address), Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name) Like '%BA%'
```

That is producing the following result:

[[image: 1]]

While if I remove a %, writing "Like 'BA%'" (instead of '%BA%') the SELECT is empty.
I really cannot understand the reason for that.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards,

Comment: Why do you need to CONCAT in the where clause? can't you just do `WHERE Brands.Extension = 'BA'` ?

Comment: That's just a dummy db I'm using while developing my .NET webapp, so of course you can't tell the need looking at those 3 rows, but the final db will be quite the big guy. It's too long to explain the reason why, let's just say that I prefer a more generic (and adaptable) query instead of spending several more lines of code in my webapp.

Comment: Is it more "adaptable" if it doesn't work? And be careful about what you think this actually does. If your goal is to find rows there BA is in one of the columns, this query does not do exactly that. Your concatenation could generate a string where the B is at the end of one column and the A is at the start of the following column. No one but you knows your goal but this approach does not have a good smell.

Comment: Thanks SMor, my original WHERE clause (in another post) was like this:
WHERE '%BA001%' IN (Scopes.Name...)
Then I was told I couldn't use wildcards and IN, and I have been suggested to go with CONCAT and Like... now I understand what CONCAT really does, and it's not the best approach. Is there a way to avoid an infinite series of OR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LIKE` pattern matches the *entire* string.

So, `'%BA%'` looks for `'BA'` anywhere in the string.  But, `'BA%'` looks only for strings that begin with `'BA'`.  And in your case, that probably means that `scopes.name` begins with `'BA'`.

More recent versions of SQL Server support `concat_ws()` which allows you to do something like:

```
WHERE CONCAT_WS('|', '|', Scopes.Name, Brands.Extension, . . .) Like '%|BA%'
```

This would check that each column starts with `'BA'`.  It is something of a hack.  It is probably better to be explicit:

```
WHERE Scopes.Name LIKE 'BA%' OR
      Brands.Extension LIKE 'BA%' OR
      . . .
```

Or perhaps:

```
WHERE 'BA' IN (LEFT(Scopes.Name, 2), LEFT(Brands.Extension, 2), . . .)
```

Comment: You said "But, 'BA%' looks only for strings that begin with 'BA'. And in your case, that probably means that scopes.name begins with 'BA'."  It's Brands.Extension beginning with BA, and that's exactly the reason why I was expecting for the SELECT to contain 2 rows (the third one in my picture is there due to country alBAnia of the 3rd record). I still cannot understand the logic behind, I have read your answer a couple of times, but it seems you are confirming what I was expecting, while the result instead is an empty table. :(

Comment: Gordon's answer has a typo. Using concatenation and `like 'BA%' means that only rows where Scopes.Name starts with 'BA' will be included - and you have no such rows (as your sample demonstrates).

Comment: @SMor . . . I don't see where the typo is.  That is what the answer says.  Note that if `scopes.Name` is `''`, then the beginning moves to the next string.

Comment: I get CONCAT is not doing what I was expecting. But is there a way to avoid an infinite series of OR to do what I need?

Comment: @LucaS. . . . I think this answers your question.  Put separators between the strings.